# A continuously differentiable function has a continuous total derivative

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

$\textbf{Proposition:}$ Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^k$ be a totally-differentiable function. Then the derivative map $$df:U\to \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}:x\mapsto df(x)$$ is continuous under the operator norm $||A|| = \sup_{|v|\leq1}\{||Av||\}$.

$\textbf{Proof 1 (incorrect)}$: Since $f$ is totally differentiable, it is a $C^1$-function. Meaning all its partial derivatives exist and are continuous. Take a convergent sequence $x_n\to a$ in $U$, we will show $df(x_n) \to df(a)$ under the operator norm.

Choose $\varepsilon>0$. Since for all $i$ and $j$, the partial derivatives $\partial_jf_i$ are continuous, there are $N_{ij}>0$ such that if $n\geq N_{ij}$ then $||\partial_jf_i(x_n)-\partial_jf_i(a)||<\varepsilon/\sqrt{kn}$. Take $N = \max_{i,j}\{N_{ij}\}$, if now $n\geq N$, then
\begin{align}
||df(x_n)-df(a)||&\leq ||df(x_n)-df(a)||_2 =||df(x_n-a)||_2\\
&=\left(\sum_{i\leq k}\sum_{j\leq n}\partial_jf_i(x_n-a)^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{i\leq k}\sum_{j\leq n}\left(\dfrac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{kn}}\right)^2\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{\dfrac{kn\varepsilon^2}{kn}} = \varepsilon.
\end{align}
Since $||\cdot||\leq ||\cdot||_2$. Hence, $df(x_n)\to df(a)$.

$\textbf{Question}$: Is this proof correct?

> $\textbf{Edit}$: I have rewritten the proof:
>
> $\textbf{Proof 2 (correct)}$: Since $f$ is totally differentiable, it is a $C^1$-function. Meaning all its partial derivatives exist and are continuous. Take a convergent sequence $x_n\to a$ in $U$, we will show $df(x_n) \to df(a)$ under the operator norm.
>
> Choose $\varepsilon>0$. Since for all $i$ and $j$, the partial derivatives $\partial_jf_i$ are continuous, there are $N_{ij}>0$ such that if $n\geq N_{ij}$ then $|\partial_jf_i(x_n)-\partial_jf_i(a)|<\varepsilon/\sqrt{kn}$. Take $N = \max_{i,j}\{N_{ij}\}$. If now $n\geq N$, then
> \begin{align}
> ||df(x_n)-df(a)||&\leq ||df(x_n)-df(a)||_2\\
> &=\left(\sum_{i\leq k}\sum_{j\leq n}\big(\partial_jf_i(x_n)-\partial_jf_i(a)\big)^2\right)^{1/2}\\
> &\leq \left(\sum_{i\leq k}\sum_{j\leq n}\left(\dfrac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{kn}}\right)^2\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{\dfrac{kn\varepsilon^2}{kn}} = \varepsilon.
> \end{align}
> Since $||\cdot||\leq ||\cdot||_2$. Hence, $df(x_n)\to df(a)$.

Comment: $x\mapsto df$ might not be linear, so your first equality is not a priori true. You seem to be confusing it with the fact that $df(x)$ is a linear map. However, given that your definition of Total Differentiability requires continuous partial derivatives, you can just apply continuity at $a$, that seems to be what the line before your calculations hint at.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou yes, true. Thanks!

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I have edited the proof.

Comment: You are basically asking whether the continuity of a matrix-valued function is equivalent to the continuity of each entry. Which is true, essentially because each norm on the space of matrices is equivalent to each other.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, I guess that's right! That is actually a way more interesting approach to this question. I have heard before that norms on finite-dimensional vector spaces induce the same topologies, but I'd like to see some references to this claim.

Comment: A proof of the fact that all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent (in the sense that they generate same topologies) can be found in Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus Chapter 4, Theorem 7.4 Corollary 2 (page 218) (the book can be found freely online just type the name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof 2 is correct. Proof 1 is not, since $df$ needn't be linear.

The whole statement can be reduced to something much more elegant. Consider the following without proof:

> $\textbf{Claim:}$ All norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent in the topological sense. That is, they induce the same topology (yet the metric space will be different).

Using this fact, it is easily seen (by picking some appropriate norm) that for the normed space of matrices, if the entries of the matrix are continuous, so too is the matrix.

Hence, since $f$ is $C^1$, the linear map represented by the matrix $(\partial_jf_i)_{ij}$ will be continuous since its entries are continuous.

Furthermore, the following claim is then a corollary:

> $\textbf{Corollary:}$ The function $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$ $\textit{if and only if}$ the derivative map $df$ is continuous on $U$.

$\textbf{Proof}$: one implication is proved above. Likewise, suppose $df$ is continuous. By picking some appropriate norm (say, the $||\cdot||_2$-norm), one can see that if the matrix is continuous, so too are the entries. Hence, for all $i$ and $j$, the functions $\partial_jf_i$ are continuous. (Existence of the partial derivatives is assumed)